# Post request for bulk API is giving status code of 406, How to resolve it?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I am using Elastic search 6.1 version
My data is appending correctly and I am adding '\n' at the end of the request.

My code is as follows:

```
def insert_in_bulk(self, filee, rtype):
    U = urljoin(self.args.host, "/_bulk")
    body = []
    f = open(filee)
    for line in f:
        action = {
                'index' :{
                '_index' : self.args.index,
                '_type' : rtype,
                  }
                }
        item = {
            'word' : line.strip()
            }

        body.append(json.dumps(action))
        body.append(json.dumps(item))

    f.close()

    body = '\n'.join(body)+'\n'
    success = False
    try:
        r = requests.post(U, data=body)
        self.log.info("after request")
        if r.status_code == 200:
            success = True
        r = r.json()
        self.log.info("inserted %s items of type = %s", self.args.index , rtype)
    except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt): raise
    except:
          self.log.exception("during bulk index")

    if not success:
             self.log.error("failed to index records of type = %s", rtype)
```

I am using the python to connect to elastic search.

I got the answer from this link
[Bulk index document from JSON file into ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932284/bulk-index-document-from-json-file-into-elasticsearch)

I have to pass the header to the request as application/x-ndjson.

Comment: Can you remove the initial new line, that might be the culprit

Comment: a = ["1", "2"]       print  '\n'.join(a)+'\n'     "1" in newline and "2" in new line, It might not be the error.

Comment: r = requests.post(U, data=body)  at this line I am getting status 406, which is saying that inappropriate request.

Comment: @Val  Ok, will check.

Comment: can you print out the body before sending it?

Comment: yes, I am printing @val

Comment: this is not legible, update your question instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is quite some time question is asked, but i want to give a solution that has worked for me in most case,

```
def insert_in_bulk(self, filee, rtype):
    U = urljoin(self.args.host, "/_bulk")
    body = []
    f = open(filee)
    for line in f:
        action = {
                'index' :{
                '_index' : self.args.index,
                '_type' : rtype,
                  }
                }
        item = {
            'word' : line.strip()
            }

        body.append(json.dumps(action))
        body.append(json.dumps(item))

    f.close()


    payload = ""
    for l in body:
        payload = payload + f"{l} \n"
    data = payload.encode('utf-8')

    r = requests.post(U, data=data, headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-ndjson"})
    print(r.text)
```